# MySQL - Truncated incorrect datetime value on update statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, update, datetime

I have an application which produces log files. These log files include a `Timestamp` field in the format `2015-08-25T09:35:01 UTC`.
(there will be approximately 60 logs produced at 0.25 GB per day).

I need to import these log files into MySQL for analysis. But I have a problem converting the `Timestamp` to `DateTime`.

example:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  `TIMESTAMP` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVENT_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test1 (`TIMESTAMP`)
VALUES 
('2015-08-25T09:35:01 UTC'),
('2015-08-25T09:36:01 UTC'),
('2015-08-25T09:37:01 UTC'),
('2015-08-25T09:38:01 UTC'),
('2015-08-25T09:39:01 UTC');
```

So far so good. I can now run a `SELECT` query to get the `datetime`

```
SELECT CAST(`TIMESTAMP` AS datetime) FROM test1;
```

But, if I try to update the table with the `datetime` format I get an error

```
UPDATE test1 SET `EVENT_TIME` = CAST(`TIMESTAMP` AS datetime);

Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-08-25T09:35:01 UTC'
```

Is there a way to do this? as I really need the datetime field in the database, so I don't have to do the `CAST` every time I run a query.

I was also looking to partition the table by date, as there will be a lot of data produced, and so I only want to keep the minimum amount of data, and then drop the oldest partitions once I am done.

Comment: DateTime uses different format "2015-08-25 09:35:01" in general, you may skip - : and even spaces, but I thing adding the T and UTC is the problem. You will probably want to use `STR_TO_DATE()` http://stackoverflow.com/a/11226328/1786423 unless you can format the timestamp beforehand,

Comment: cheers, unfortunately I get the same result `UPDATE test1 SET EVENT_TIME = STR_TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s');` `Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2015-08-25T09:35:01 UTC'`

Comment: `UPDATE test1 SET EVENT_TIME = STR_TO_DATE(TIMESTAMP, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s UTC');` - you have to match entire string, including the ' UTC' suffix

Comment: excellent, that appears to have fixed it, and I learned something new. cheers.

Comment: The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) states that extra characters are ignored: 
"Scanning starts at the beginning of str and fails if format is found not to match. Extra characters at the end of str are ignored."

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE partitioned_test1 (
  `TIMESTAMP` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EVENT_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(`EVENT_TIME`)) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2023-01-01')),
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2023-02-01')),
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2023-03-01')),
  ...
  PARTITION pN VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```